# Expressing an integral in terms of incomplete beta function

Tags: integration

How do we prove the following identity :
$I(p,q)=\int_0^1 t^p\,(2-t)^q\,dt=2^{p+q+1} B_{\frac{1}{2}}(p+1,q+1)$ where $B$ stands  for incomplete beta integral?Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised it can be easily shown.In the integral
$$ I(p,q)=\int_0^1 t^p\,(2-t)^q\,dt$$
substitute $$ t=2u$$  so that  $dt=2du$.In terms of the new variable the new variable beocomes:
$$ I(p,q)=\int_0^{1/2} (2u)^p\,(2-2u)^q\,2du$$ which simplifies to :
$$I(p,q)=2^{p+q+1}\int_0^{1/2} u^p\,(1-u)^q\,du=2^{p+q+1} B_{\frac{1}{2}}(p+1,q+1)$$